# change directory in batch file using variable

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Here's the question:

```
set Pathname = C:\Program Files
cd %Pathname%
pause
```

The above doesn't change the directory, as I would expect. Can anybody please tell me why?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `set` statement doesn't treat spaces the way you expect; your variable is really named `Pathname[space]` and is equal to `[space]C:\Program Files`.

Remove the spaces from both sides of the `=` sign, and put the value in double quotes:

```
set Pathname="C:\Program Files"
```

Also, if your command prompt is not open to C:\, then using `cd` alone can't change drives.

Use

```
cd /d %Pathname%
```

or

```
pushd %Pathname%
```

instead.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the quotes aren't in general required to use SET with a string containing spaces. `SET C:\Program Files` would also have worked.

Comment: @MonkeyPushButton, I think you meant `set Pathname=C:\Program Files`, but yeah, it does work with spaces

Comment: It depends on the command. `cd` and `pushd` behave nicely with or without quotes around the path. `md`, `rd` and `copy` don't, to name a few. I generally put quotes around all paths that use spaces, just to be safe.

Comment: The `/d` was needed for me since I was CD'ing to a different drive EG, cd from `C:` to `G:` required `/d`

Comment: Thanks! I needed /d.

Answer (score -5):

simple way to do this... here are the example

```
cd program files
cd poweriso
piso mount D:\<Filename.iso> <Virtual Drive>
Pause
```

this will mount the ISO image to the specific drive...use

Comment: This does not answer the question.