# how to use cd command properly in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am new to batch scripting, just trying to write a simple batch file that would go to the directory that I frequently use, without having to do cd everytime.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD /
CD D:
CD programming/
```

when I save and try to run this it gives error:

```
the system cannot find the file specified path
```

Even though these commands run fine while doing it directly on prompt

Comment: Using backslashes will help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change directory in batch file using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133244/change-directory-in-batch-file-using-variable)

Comment: one liner answer `cd D:/programming/`

Comment: `cd` doesn't change drives unless you include the `/d` switch. You need one line: `cd /d D:\programming`. Note that I've used backslashes, not forward slashes as well.

Comment: Btw: Windows and DOS tag don't make sense together in 99,9999999% of cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, the Windows path separator is `\` but not `/`.

Then you need to get aware that there is a current directory for *every* drive to fully understand what is going on.

But anyway, here is an adapted version of your code with some explanations:

```cmd
rem /* This changes to the root directory of the drive you are working on (say `C:`);
rem    note that I replaced `/` by `\`, which is the correct path separator: */
cd \
rem /* This changes the current directory of drive `D:` to the current directory of drive `D:`,
rem    note that this does NOT switch to the specified drive as there is no `/D` option: */
cd D:
rem /* This is actually the same as `cd programming` and changes to the sub-directory
rem    `programming` of your current working directory: */
cd programming\
rem /* The final working directory is now `C:\programming`, assuming that the original
rem    working drive was `C:`. */
```

However, what I think you are trying to achieve is the following:

```cmd
rem // This switches to the drive `D:`; regard that there is NO `cd` command:
D:
rem // This changes to the root directory of the drive you are working on, which is `D:`:
cd \
rem // This changes into the directory `programming`:
cd programming
rem // The final working directory is now `D:\programming`.
```

This can be shortened to:

```cmd
D:
cd \programming
```

Or even this:

```cmd
rem // Note the `/D` option that is required to also switch to the given drive:
cd /D D:\programming
```

Comment: actually I made a silly mistake, I wrote cd D: instead of D:, Now I understood

Answer (score 0):

When you use

cd d:

the current directory of D: may not be D:\

To set the root you need to use CD D:\

In Windows, use backslashes

Comment: Well, although it is correct what you are saying (since every drive has got its own current directory), this does not switch to drive `D:` unless you add the `/D` option…

Comment: What I said above is that if the D: drive was previously set to a directory other than the root, say D:\work, when you use CD D:, it goes back to the previous directory in D:, that is, D:\work, where there is no a directory "programing".

Comment: You are right, `cd D:\ `changes the current directory of drive `D:` (independent on what drive you are currently working on); `cd D:` is useless, because you change the current directory of drive `:D` to, well, the current directory of that drive `D:`. Anyway, what I was trying to say is this: when you are working on drive `C:`, you can type either `cd D:` or `cd D:\ `but you will still be on drive `C:`, unless you use `cd /D` instead of `cd`, then you change the drive as well.